# How to import a spreadsheet.csv gephi in an undirected style?

Tags: gephi

I am working with gephi. I am having trouble in importing csv srpeadsheet, because it is selected automatically in a directed format style when I apply for edges criteria. Is there any way to select it as undirected?

Is there any explanation for these problems?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify a `Type` column in your CSV that will be set to *"Undirected"* and will be imported as string